# How to close a Realm before deleting all the files associated with it?

Tags: swift, realm

I would like to update a non-sync Realm (`default.realm`) by deleting all the files associated with it via the `Realm.deleteFiles(for:)` function before replacing it with an in-memory Realm via the `Realm.writeCopy(configuration:)` function.

```
func replaceDefaultRealmWithInMemoryData() throws {
    let anyFilesWereDeleted = try Realm.deleteFiles(for: Self.defaultRealmConfiguration)
    guard anyFilesWereDeleted else { ... }
    let inMemoryRealm = try Self.inMemoryRealm
    try inMemoryRealm.writeCopy(configuration: Self.defaultRealmConfiguration)
}
```

The operation always fails because the Realm seems to be already open elsewhere.

> Cannot delete files of an open Realm: '.../default.realm' is still in use.

The documentation specifies :

> If you specifically want to ensure a Realm instance is destroyed (for example, if you wish to open a Realm, check some property, and then possibly delete the Realm file and re-open it), place the code which uses the Realm within an autoreleasepool {} and ensure you have no other strong references to it. Source : https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html

I made sure to isolate each use of the Realm in an `autoreleasepool {}` block, but the error remains. Is there a way to manually close a Realm, i.e. something like `Realm.close()`?

Comment: This is a very common issue; any time Realm is touched, it's considered open and the files cannot be deleted. Enclosing it in functions that allow it to go out of scope is one technique and using autoreleasepools is another. Often times the underlying issue is due to a singleton design pattern to access Realm; often called a `RealmService`- once it's referenced, it's open. Can you update your question with the code showing how you're accessing Realm?